# Google Maps intent returning error: No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-intent, textview

I have a `navigate` method:

```
    public void navigate(String coordinates){

        Uri intentUri = Uri.parse("geo"+coordinates);
        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        mapIntent.setData(intentUri);
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        getContext().startActivity(mapIntent);
    }
```

which is called when I click on a `TextView`:

```
        TextView location = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.location);
        location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                navigate(currentAttraction.getLocation());
            }
        });
```

However, when the app is running and I click on the `TextView`, the app `crashes and I get this error`:

```
2020-01-15 21:29:20.164 17438-17438/com.example.android.explorecapetown E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.explorecapetown, PID: 17438
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo-33.920864,18.418210 pkg=com.google.android.apps.maps }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2051)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1709)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5192)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5150)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5521)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5489)
        at com.example.android.explorecapetown.AttractionAdapter.navigate(AttractionAdapter.java:72)
        at com.example.android.explorecapetown.AttractionAdapter$1.onClick(AttractionAdapter.java:46)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

The device does have Google Maps.

I am very new to using a Maps intent so I was hoping someone could give me an idea of what I'm doing wrong.

**P.S.**

Take note this occurs within an Adapter class:

```
public class AttractionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Attraction> {


    public AttractionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Attraction> attractions) {
        super(context, 0, attractions);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        final Attraction currentAttraction = getItem(position);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.attraction_image);
        imageView.setImageResource(currentAttraction.getImageResourceId());

        TextView attractionName = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.attraction_name);
        attractionName.setText(currentAttraction.getName());

        TextView location = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.location);
        location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                navigate(currentAttraction.getLocation());
            }
        });

        // Find the ImageView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID image.
        TextView contact = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.contact);
        // Check if an image is provided for this word or not
        if (currentAttraction.hasContact()) {
            // If an image is available, display the provided image based on the resource ID
            contact.setText(currentAttraction.getContact());
            // Make sure the view is visible
            contact.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // Otherwise hide the ImageView (set visibility to GONE)
            contact.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return listItemView;
    }

    public void navigate(String coordinates){

        Uri intentUri = Uri.parse("geo"+coordinates);
        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        mapIntent.setData(intentUri);
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        getContext().startActivity(mapIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always safe to check is there any activity to handle the intent or not before firing any implicit intent.

> **Caution**: It's possible that a user won't have any apps that handle the implicit intent you send to startActivity(). Or, an app may be
>   inaccessible because of profile restrictions or settings put into
>   place by an administrator. If that happens, the call fails and your
>   app crashes. To verify that an activity will receive the intent, call
>   resolveActivity() on your Intent object. If the result is non-null,
>   there is at least one app that can handle the intent and it's safe to
>   call startActivity(). If the result is null, do not use the intent

```
//Uri intentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194");

Uri intentUri = Uri.parse("geo:"+coordinates);
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mapIntent.setData(intentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");

if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
    context.startActivity(mapIntent);
} else {
    //Show info
}
```

Check official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#intent_requests)

Comment: Thank you. The intent is now opening Google Maps, but instead of displaying the location, it's just showing a blank screen with the search bar on top and no map.

Comment: Can you add here what your **coordinates** looks like? Also Can you try with sample data like **geo:37.7749,-122.4194**?

Comment: It seems to be working now, I'm really not sure what changed. It might have been the device playing up. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the colon after geo:

```
Uri intentUri = Uri.parse("geo:"+coordinates);
```

This should be the reason why it finds no activity associated.

The format to use the geo: intent to display a map at a specified location and zoom level:

`geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom`

And the zoom is optional.

The docs can be found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents

That is the reason of the crash. And, as an extra, you should check is there any activity to handle the intent. Because other devices could not be the maps app installed.

Answer (score 0):

public void navigate(Context context, String coordinates){

```
    Uri intentUri = Uri.parse("geo:"+coordinates);
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    mapIntent.setData(intentUri);
    mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
    context.startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

navigate(getContext, currentAttraction.getLocation());